# Akka remoting binds to hostname instead of bind-hostname

Tags: networking, akka, akka-remote-actor

## Context

I am trying to run an akka application on a node and make it work with other nodes using akka remoting capabilities.

My node has an IP address, `10.254.55.10`, and there is an external IP, `10.10.10.44`, redirecting to the former. This external IP is the one on which I want other nodes to contact me.

Extract from my akka app config:

```
  akka {
            remote {
                    netty.tcp {
                            hostname = "10.10.10.44"
                            port = 2551

                            bind-hostname = "10.254.55.10"
                            bind-port = 2551
                    }
            }
  }
```

I know everything works fine on the network side, because when I listen on my IP with netcat, I can send messages to myself via telnet using the external IP.

In other words, when running these two commands in separate shells:

`$ nc -l 10.254.55.10 2551`

`$ telnet 10.10.10.44 2551`

I'm able to communicate with myself, proving the network redirection works fine between the two IPs.

## Problem

When launching the application, it crashes with a bind error:

```
INFO Remoting - Starting remoting
ERROR a.r.t.n.NettyTransport - failed to bind to /10.10.10.44:2551, shutting down Netty transport
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[...]
Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /10.10.10.44:2551
[...]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
[...]
INFO a.r.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator - Shutting down remote daemon.
```

I assume what makes it crash is that it tries to bind to an IP that is not present locally (i.e. `10.10.10.44`). But what I don't understand in first place is why akka is even trying to bind to `10.10.10.44`, since it is not my bind-hostname (which is `10.254.55.10`). [This doc page](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/remoting.html) seemed pretty clear to me on that matter, yet it doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The project I was working with was based on akka 2.3.4, in which `bind-hostname` and `bind-port` configuration keys do not exist. I upgraded to latest version at the time, akka 2.4.1, and it solved the problem.